# Unable to create bar chart from d3 using URL

Tags: json, url, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create bar chart from json file which is a URL but i am unable to do so please help me, as i am new to d3. The code is here please tell me where i am making mistake.

```
var width = 960,
  height = 500;
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var chart = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

generateChart();

function generateChart() {
  d3.json('http://dataserver.org:8009/topic/domain/cancer',
    function(error, data) {
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.occurrence
      })]);
      var barWidth = width / data.length; //width of each bar
      var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ", 0)";
        });
      bar.append("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.occurrence);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.occurrence);
        })
        .attr("width", barWidth - 1);
      bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.occurrence) - 10;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.authorName;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Did you inspect your JavaScript console for errors?  My first guess would a CORS violation since you are pulling data from another server/domain.

Comment: Sorry i have no idea about it

Comment: @Sam : tried the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of cross domain as I checked your API. Assuming that you are fetching d3.js from CDN, I am suggesting a change. Your chart will depend on "institute" as it is containing all the required values for chart. So I changed it as per structure your API's response.

**in some case data was coming as "undefined" so I am fetching d3.js from CDN

Here is whole modified file:-

```
function generateChart() {
d3.json('http://srvgal78.deri.ie:8009/topic/domain/cancer',
function(error, data) {

    data = data.institute;

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.occurrence
  })]);


  var barWidth = width / data.length; //width of each bar
  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ", 0)";
    });
  bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.occurrence);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.occurrence);
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1);
  bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.occurrence) - 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.authorName;
    });
});
```

};

Comment: It worked for me......in case of any problem just replace your d3 inclusion with   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>..............Bar graph was the output...:):)

Comment: welcome Sam!!....in case you want to see some of my work...here is the link...http://grafitome.github.io